# Can I add application shortcuts to be on this panel? XFCE

Tags: linux, debian, xfce

Is there any way to add application shortcuts to the default panel in Debian 10 XFCE environment?[image]

If not, are there any alternate options to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the panel preferences:

- Got to items
- Click the plus icon to add an item
- Add a laucher
- Click on the added launcher and edit it
- Click the plus icon on the edit pop up
- Choose a program

Answer (score 0):

From the panel preferences:

- Disable **Lock panel**
- Enable **Automatically increase the length**

Also you can adjust the length under **Measurement** .

[xfce4 : Preferences](https://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences)